Create Pipeline via Azure Powershell and pipelineReturnValue activity is not properly created
I try to run this command in Azure Powershell
Set-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -Force -ResourceGroupName MY_DEV_RESOURCE_GRP -DataFactoryName MYADF001 -Name PL_PROCESS_API -DefinitionFile ./PL_PROCESS_API.json

Inside a PL_PROCESS_API.json file is containing this content
...{
            "name": "Activity_Return",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Process API data",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "pipelineReturnValue",
                "value": [
                    {
                        "key": "strCommaSeparatedString",
                        "value": {
                            "type": "Expression",
                            "content": "@activity('Process API data').output.Holiday"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "setSystemVariable": true
            }
        }...

When I run this command the sections of pipelineReturnValue in type properties in ADF when the command run successfully will be like this
"typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "pipelineReturnValue",
                "value": "[{\"key\":\"strCommaSeparatedString\",\"value\":{\"type\":\"Expression\",\"content\":\"@length(activity('Process API data').output.Holiday)\"}}]"
            }

I would like to know how to fix this?

are you getting any error? what is your expected output?

No error raise up, the exepected output might be the same as the JSON content in Json file for that pipeline.

As you see in the section of typeProperties.value it have to be json array, but it appear in ADF as JSON String.

I have posted the answer, please check if it solves your query or not.

I just dropped a comment on your answer.

I have tried the same PowerShell script with below JSON which is similar as your pipeline from my end.
{
    "name": "test2",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Activity_Return",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Process API data",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "pipelineReturnValue",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "key": "strCommaSeparatedString",
                            "value": {
                                "type": "Expression",
                                "content": "@activity('Process API data').output.data"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "setSystemVariable": true
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Process API data",
                "type": "WebActivity",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "url": "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2"
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "var1": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}

The pipeline got created with correct expression as shown below.

I have tried by changing some code in the pipeline JSON and the only time I got the similar JSON string for the return variable is when I had set the "setSystemVariable" property to false in the typeProperties of the Activity_Return activity.
This is the activity JSON for your reference:
{
                "name": "Activity_Return",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Process API data",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "pipelineReturnValue",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "key": "strCommaSeparatedString",
                            "value": {
                                "type": "Expression",
                                "content": "@activity('Process API data').output.data"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "setSystemVariable": false 
                }
            }

Similar Result:

When the setSystemVariable property is false, the pipeline variable will not be considered as a pipeline return variable and the expression for that will be considered as a string. So, make sure the setSystemVariable property is set to true in the pipeline JSON.

Actually my setSystemVariable is already set to true but it still occur with this problem, I'm not sure that is because the version of Azure Powershell or not, it is 3.0.0, what's version had you tried?

My Azure Powershell version is 12.4.0. https://i.imgur.com/E8oIwKk.png. You can check by updating yours to latest. follow this doc.

I tried to use Azure Cloud Shell that have version of Az.DataFactory 1.18.8, it working properly so I will try to upgrade this module.
